# Javascript: enable all submit buttons on the page after 3 second

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have multiple forms & submit buttons on a page.

I want to disable the user from being able to submit any of the forms until 3 seconds after the page loads.

For this purpose I have put `disabled="disabled"` into the html of each submit button.

Now how can I get it to automatically enable all of these submit buttons after 3 seconds, without having to specify the ID of each one individually?

Comment: By using a selection method that does not rely on the ID of an element.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Perhaps [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors) will help. Or you could use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JS :

```
window.onload = function(){
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  setTimeout(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
    buttons[i].disabled=false;
    }
  },3000);
}
```

JQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('button').attr('disabled','false');
  },3000);  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, can I use: `document.getElementsByTagName(\'submit\');`?

Comment: @Alasdair - No, you'd have to search for `input` elements and then check the type within the loop. Or you can use `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]')`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to put a common class to all the elements, and access them at once for disable / enables

Try this - make the class as `Formelement`

Now use this

```
setTimeOut(function(){
    $('.Formelement').attr('disabled','false');
},3000);
```